# Subclass is not returning the value - Java

Tags: function, subclass

I'm newbie to core java. I'm studying java myself. I've learned some basic stuffs in java. Now i'm working out inheritance concept. I wrote a code create two class. One is a superclass called "Inhersam" and another one is subclass called "subclass". I've created a function getgid() in subclass and i'm trying to call that function from superclass. Hello World!!! string is printing, but function is not returning any value. what is the problem?

```
class subclass
{
    int getgid()
    {
        return 31;
    }

}
public class Inhersam extends subclass
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Inhersam l=new Inhersam();
            /*subclass l=new subclass();*/
            l.getgid();
            System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
        }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not returning the value? You're just never doing anything with or printing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: The reason "31" is not being printed in the console is because you didnt put the function inside `System.out.println()`.

Also, I find a bit weird that you are creating an instance of the class you're already in, You shouldnt have to do this `Inhersam l=new Inhersam();` just calling `getgid()` would do the job, as you are already defining the method in its parent class.. (just make sure to define the access modifier to be `protected`) like this: `protected int getgid() {}`

This is how your code should look:

```
class subclass
{
    protected int getgid()
    {
        return 31;
    }

}
public class Inhersam extends subclass
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World!!!" + getgid());
        }

}
```

Comment: You are welcome, make sure to mark this answer as valid if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, you're just not using the returned value so you cant see it.. to see it, replace `l.getgid();` by `System.out.println(l.getgid());`